# VBA 7.0: Compiler error on GoTo inside a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to continue the for loop in the if condition below, but VBA complains compile error: "Next without For".
I am using "GoTo", because there is no "continue" keyword in VBA, such as other typical programming languages.

Any idea what is wrong here?

```
For RowIndex = 2 To lastrow

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$b$" & RowIndex) = "" Then
      GoTo EndLoop

    output_string = setproperty & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$b$" & RowIndex) & " [ get_ports " & """" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$g$" & RowIndex) & """" & " ]"
    Print #1, output_string

    output_string = setpropertyiostandard & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$k$" & RowIndex) & " [ get_ports """ & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$g$" & RowIndex) & """" & " ]"
    Print #1, output_string


    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$k$" & RowIndex) = "LVCMOS18" Then
        'Debug.Print "found" & RowIndex
        output_string = "set_property DRIVE 8 [ get_ports " & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$g$" & RowIndex) & "]"
        Print #1, output_string
    End If

EndLoop:
Next RowIndex
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first If/Then is left open, need to close that up within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can change the test from = to <>.  Another trick is to use while true loop

```
For RowIndex = 2 to LastRow
  While true
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$b$" & RowIndex) = "" Then Exit Do

    Rest of your code here

    Exit Do '<- Remember to do this or you'll be caught in an infinite loop
  Loop
Next
```